# Problems formatting code with <% %> in SO questions

Tags: support, code-formatting, troubleshooting

I was editing a question during the review and I'm having troubles formatting this code: can anyone tell me how to do it? The code is not shown in the question body!

[...]

- Added this to my masterpage:

> 

[...]

You can see that the code is not shown!

This is the hard-copied code:

First line: <%: Scripts.Render("~/js/mainJS.js") %>

Second line:<%: Styles.Render("~/css/mainStyle.min.css") %>

---

EDIT

The question I was editing is this one:
[Bundling css and javascript with webforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757870/bundling-css-and-javascript-with-webforms)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of putting them in blockquotes ">" put them in code block by prefixing them with 4 spaces.

```
<%: Scripts.Render("~/js/mainJS.js") %>

<%: Styles.Render("~/css/mainStyle.min.css") %>
```

When putting them after list, you have ot prefix them by 8 spaces. (4 spaces is the indent of the list block, then 4 more ot specify code block)

- list

  ```
  <%: Scripts.Render("~/js/mainJS.js") %>

  <%: Styles.Render("~/css/mainStyle.min.css") %>
  ```

Comment: That was the trick! I tried with 4 spaces but not with 8. Great! :) Thanks.